# Is it important for an app to work on both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

We've been working on a iPhone app for the last couple of months, an app that will only be targeted for the iPhone.

I have read through the [Review Guidelines](http://photos.appleinsider.com/App%20Store%20Review%20Guidelines%20-%20App%20Store%20Resource%20Centerai.pdf) and spotted a potential reason for the app getting rejected under the '**Functionality**' category.

*"Iphone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution."*

In xcode we have targeted the app for iPhone only. To my mind this means that the app should only be available to iPhone users in the App Store and shouldn't get rejected.

My question is - Are we going to face possible rejection if the app doesn't display propertly on an iPad? Eventhough it is only targeted for iPhone?

Comment: No you won't get rejection if you are going to launch it for iPhone only. Lots of app are out there in Apple store those supports only iPhone or only iPad. so go ahead.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I had an app reject, which was iPhone only, because of a crash when the app was run in iPhone mode in the iPad. It was only a small bug which was easily fixed. But Yes if you app does not work in iPhone mode on the iPad you can get your app rejected.

Comment: The app should only work on an iPad, but you don't have to release it for iPad. You can test this by opening your app on the iPad simulator or an development iPad device.

Comment: Ok thanks, it will only be targeted for iPhone users so we will go ahead and develop for iPhone only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPad owners can download and run ALL iPhone apps in the App Store.  Your app must run correctly on an iPad in iPhone mode.  You should test your app on an actual iPad device before releasing it to make sure there are no issues.  In general, if your app works fine on an iPhone 3GS, you should be fine.